# Foundation center multiple columns into row

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I try to center columns into a row.

There is the simple code :

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:black;">

      <div class="large-2 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="days" style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div>
      <div class="large-2 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="hours" style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div> 
      <div class="large-2 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="minutes"style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div>
      <div class="large-2 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="seconds" style="opacity:0.8;"></div> 
</div>
```

And the result :

[image]

You can see, the space of row is the black background. How can i center the columns into the row ?

Comment: Please, post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hc6sN/). From the spot: you can set `display:table` to your `.row` div and set `margin:0 auto` to it's parent.

Comment: easiest way will be set margin-left:15%  on you div with 62 days

Comment: @Notulysses it's useless, http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/210/ this is responsive, you don't see anything for large screen.

Comment: @KashifQureshi It's Foundation, it's responsive... Your solution is the easiest way for large screen. But small screen don't really love margin like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use offset

```
<div class="row" style="background-color:black;">    
      <div class="large-2 large-offset-2 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="days" style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div>
      <div class="large-2 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="hours" style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div> 
      <div class="large-2 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="minutes"style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div>
      <div class="large-2 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="seconds" style="opacity:0.8;"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: My margin right are not really cool for the mobile screen, they all shifted. There is a way to apply a margin only for large screen in foundation ?

Comment: @Martialp `large-offset-2` will affect only large screens.

Comment: i speak about margin-right:0.5%;, for the space between two columns. Your solution works perfectly, it's just an aditionnal question ;)

Comment: @Martialp As far as i know not directly. But you can use Visibility Classes http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html and show another version of the columns for the mobile screen. Probably, you should start another question for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap the row in another row/column, then center the contents of that column using the provided utility classes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-10 columns large-centered">
    <div class="row">        
      <div class="large-3 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="days" style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div>
      <div class="large-3 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="hours" style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div> 
      <div class="large-3 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="minutes"style="opacity:0.8;margin-right:0.5%;"></div>
      <div class="large-3 small-6 text-center radius panel left columns" id="seconds" style="opacity:0.8;"></div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```